# Is this external DVD drive Mac compatible?

Tags: hardware

I am thinking of purchasing a Mac Mini but the lack of optical drive, makes me hesitant. I have an external super-multi DVD rewriter by Liteon (Model GP08LU10). Will this portable drive be compatible with a new Mac Mini?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know for sure is to check for yourself. If you have access to an Apple store, you can just bring it in and try it on any of their Macs there. (All Macs have the same standardized OS with the same drivers available)

That being said, the answer is most likely yes. Generic USB devices like this are typically fairly standard, and usually have great plug and play support on Macs.